# How to use Apache POI in OSGi

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, apache-poi, bndtools

I want to use Apache POI in OSGi to write an Excel workbook with the streaming, OOXML API (SXSSF). The streaming API is available since POI 3.9.

As the latest Apache POI 3.11 jars are not bundles: **What's the best way to get POI working in OSGi?**

I tried two approaches:

1. embed the jars directly in the only bundle which will be using them
2. use POI jars prewrapped as bundles

I am despairing in getting all dependencies together.

First about embedding the POI jar in my bundle: my bndtools file contains

```
-buildpath:  \
...
libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;version=file,\
libs/poi-3.11.jar;version=file,\
libs/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar;version=file,\
libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar;version=file

Private-Package:  \
...
org.openxmlformats.schemas.*,\
org.apache.poi.*,\
org.dom4j.*,\
com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.*,\
schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.*,\
schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.*,\
schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.*,\
schemasMicrosoftComVml.*
```

This results in a bundle which imports many, many things like for example `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509` and `org.junit`. I don't plan to encrypt or test in my application - so these two are probably somehow "optional". How can I specify this? Is there a good way of collecting all these dependencies?

Note: at least `org.apache.commons.codec` and `com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.lib` are additionally required, but they are already bundles.

---

Using prewrapped jars, I tried using `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi` 3.9_2. This also requires `dom4j` so I used the prewrapped `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j` but that requires at least version 1.0 of `javax.xml.stream` which my JVM/Felix OSGi advertises as "only" version `0.0.0.1_007_JavaSE`. I fixed this by hand (ugly), but then got stuck on another dependency.

**What's the good way?**

Comment: You're on the right track, hang in there :-)    
The servicemix bundles are OSGi ready, if this needs more dependencies install those, too. For the javax.xml.stream, you could also look for the corresponding bundle. Which other dependency are you missing?

Comment: On runtime, it can't find classes which are in poi-ooxml-schemas. Is there a bundle for that? Meanwhile I tried embedding it but v.3.9 has not all required classes (some ...math package is missing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Gradle with [bnd-platform](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform) to build OSGi bundles for our applications based on Maven dependencies.
No sure if this is "the good way", but this is how we build the target platform for our OSGi based applications, Apache POI being part of that. It's especially useful in cases where you have to do adaptions to bundles (e.g. make JUnit optional) or merge JARs (e.g. due to classloading issues in OSGi) to make them work.

I set up an **[example build with an Apache POI bundle](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform-minimal/blob/sample-poi/build.gradle)** (and implicitly, its POM-defined dependencies) on GitHub. You can clone it ([sample-poi](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform-minimal/tree/sample-poi) branch) and try it running `./gradlew clean bundles`. Created bundles will be in `build/plugins`.

Please note that any optional Maven dependencies will not be included by default and have to be added manually to the build, if you need them (due to [limitations in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220205/982265)).

Comment: Stempler, thank you for fast solution! Do you use Gradle to build entire, or just for dependency-bundle generation?

Comment: @Andrew Personally I only use the build for creating a P2 repository with third party dependencies that is then used in a Maven Tycho build. [Here](https://github.com/stempler/bnd-platform/issues/5) is one example mentioned where bnd-platform is used in context of an encompassing build. Maybe there is also a way to combine it with the [Wuff Gradle plugins](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff), but AFAIK nobody has tried that so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a working example of this work around but this bit of documentation may be helpful to you.

[Can POI be used with OSGI?](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1029C)

> Starting with POI 3.16 there's a workaround for OSGIs context
>   classloader handling, i.e. it replaces the threads current context
>   classloader with an implementation of limited class view. This will
>   lead to IllegalStateExceptions, as xmlbeans can't find the xml schema
>   definitions in this reduced view. The workaround is to initialize the
>   classloader delegate of POIXMLTypeLoader , which defaults to the
>   current thread context classloader. The initialization should take
>   place before any other OOXML related calls. The class in the example
>   could be any class, which is part of the poi-ooxml-schema or
>   ooxml-schema:
>   POIXMLTypeLoader.setClassLoader(CTTable.class.getClassLoader());